# Cannot access a disposed object for DbContext in .NET Core for Async method

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having a weird problem in one of my microservice web api. My async GET methods throw a **Cannot access a disposed object** exception for my DbContext except for the very first time they are invoked. I tried looking online for an answer but nothing worked. I made sure my methods are not async void and I await the necessary calls. Since my POST and DELETE methods work fine, I am fairly certain that the real culprit is the IMapper instance. I think it might always point to the first instance of the DbContext and that is why the works the first time but not the ones after. Any help or pointers would be gladly appreciated

Here are some snapshots of the code.

Startup.cs

```
...
// Add AutoMapper
        services.AddAutoMapper(new Assembly[] { typeof(AutoMapperProfile).GetTypeInfo().Assembly });

// Add DbContext using NoSQL Server Provider
services.AddDbContext<ProfileDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMongoDb(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TeamJobProfilesDatabase")));
...
```

MyController.cs

```
    // GET api/profiles
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ProfilesListViewModel>> GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetAllProfilesQuery()));
    }

    // GET api/profiles/{id}
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ProfileViewModel>> Get(int id)
    {
        return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetProfileQuery { Id = id }));
    }
```

GetAllProfilesQueryHandler.cs

```
public class GetAllProfilesQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAllProfilesQuery, ProfilesListViewModel>
{
    private readonly ProfileDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public GetAllProfilesQueryHandler(ProfileDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<ProfilesListViewModel> Handle(GetAllProfilesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return new ProfilesListViewModel
        {
            Profiles = await _context.Profiles.ProjectTo<ProfileLookupModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
        };
    }
}
```

ProfileDbContext.cs

```
[MongoDatabase("profileDb")]
public class ProfileDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ProfileDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProfileDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Domain.Entities.Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

Exception message

> {
>       "error": [
>           "Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.\r\nObject name: 'ProfileDbContext'."
>       ],
>       "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ChangeTracker()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompilationContextFactory.get_TrackQueryResults()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompilationContextFactory.Create(Boolean async)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)\r\n   at Blueshift.EntityFrameworkCore.MongoDB.Storage.MongoDbDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0`1.<CompileAsyncQuery>b__0(QueryContext queryContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Ix.NET\\Source\\System.Interactive.Async\\Aggregate.cs:line 118\r\n   at Profile.Application.Profiles.Queries.GetAllProfiles.GetAllProfilesQueryHandler.Handle(GetAllProfilesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\\Users\\Adam\\Repositories\\TeamJob\\TeamJob\\src\\Services\\Profile\\Profile.Application\\Profiles\\Queries\\GetAllProfiles\\GetAllProfilesQueryHandler.cs:line 24\r\n   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)\r\n   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)\r\n   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)\r\n   at Profile.API.Controllers.ProfilesController.GetAll() in C:\\Users\\Adam\\Repositories\\TeamJob\\TeamJob\\src\\Services\\Profile\\Profile.API\\Controllers\\ProfilesController.cs:line 19\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()"
>   }

Comment: It looks as if your handler is registered as singleton instead of per request/scope.

Comment: Is `Mediator.Send` your implementation or you used some 3rd party library? Can you provide some more info on that method, because I think the source of your problem lies within it and the way your `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler` is being resolved.

Comment: @MarkoPapic I am using the 3rdParty library MediatR for this. I will add more info on this when I come back home from work.

Comment: Wow I just hit this same exact issue yesterday.  Tearing my hair out. First time I've ever seen it and its with EF core operations I use ALL the time

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in [Mediator.Send](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Mediator.cs) method. `Mediator` class stores request handlers in a static [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```cs
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> _requestHandlers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();
```

and when the `Send` method is invoked, it uses `GetOrAdd` method on that dictionary.

```cs
var handler = (RequestHandlerWrapper<TResponse>)_requestHandlers.GetOrAdd(requestType, t => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(RequestHandlerWrapperImpl<,>).MakeGenericType(requestType, typeof(TResponse))));
```

This means, if the request handler instance doesn't already exist in the dictionary, it creates a new instance (using `Activator`) and adds it to the dictionary, but if the request handler instance already exists in the dictionary, it uses the existing one (and this is the cause of your problem).

**So, what exactly is causing your error?**

The `_requestHandlers` dictionary is `static`, which means it lives **through multiple requests**, i.e. doesn't get disposed/garbage collected at the end of the request. Your `ProfileDbContext`, when registered using `AddDbContext` method, has a [scoped lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes), which means it is **created once per request** (and disposed at the end of the request). This means you can end up in a situation where `_requestHandlers` dictionary contains an instance of `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler` that has a reference on an exposed instance of `ProfileDbContext`.

Here is what happens:

1. First request arrives.
2. `Mediator.Send(new GetProfileQuery { Id = id })` gets called.
3. `Mediator.Send(new GetProfileQuery { Id = id })` doesn't find `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler` in `_requestHandlers` dictionary, so it instantiates it and also resolves its `ProfileDbContext` dependency.
4. The request ends. `_context` field (`ProfileDbContext`) in your `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler` indsance gets disposed (because it has a `scoped` lifetime), but the `_requestHandlers` dictionary (containing `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler` instance) doesn't get disposed (because it is static).
5. Another request arrives.
6. `Mediator.Send(new GetProfileQuery { Id = id })` gets called again.
7. This time `Mediator.Send(new GetProfileQuery { Id = id })` finds `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler` instance in `_requestHandlers` dictionary **and uses the existing instance, whose `_context` field is disposed at the end of the previous request**.
8. `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler` tries to access the disposed `_context` field, and gets the "Cannot access a disposed object" error.

**Possible solution**

Don't let `Mediator.Send` resolve `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler`s dependencies.

Maybe pass `IServiceProvider serviceProvider` to your `GetAllProfilesQueryHandler` and let it resolve its dependencies as needed:

```cs
public class GetAllProfilesQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAllProfilesQuery, ProfilesListViewModel>
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public GetAllProfilesQueryHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<ProfilesListViewModel> Handle(GetAllProfilesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return new ProfilesListViewModel
        {
            ProfileDbContext context = (ProfileDbContext)this._serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ProfileDbContext));
            IMapper mapper = (IMapper)this._serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMapper));

            Profiles = await context.Profiles.ProjectTo<ProfileLookupModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
        };
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As @Lucian Bargaoanu pointed out in comments, you can resolve handlers through DI, as in https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: You're supposed to resolve handlers through DI as in https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.

Comment: Worked for me. I wanted to invoke a function at intervals and the function required access to the dbcontext at every interval. Thanks @Marko for your solution.